# how can I get current model name in Yii Framework using with controller name

Tags: yii

I have a problem about Yii framework.
I want to call current modelClass name using controller name.
For example my controller name is UserController and model name is User.
I want to call modelClass name dynamically.Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your controller name like below:

```
$controllerName= $this->id;
```

Your model would be probably:

```
$modelName=ucfirst($controllerName);
```

Then, call your model like below:

```
$model=new $modelName();
```

Or,

```
$allUsers=$model::model()->findAll();
```

Please note that, I assumed that your controller name is `UserController` and your model name is `User`.

Comment: ucfirst($this->id);  code is true, thank you so much for reply

Answer (score 0):

The relation between model and controller is purely conventional but for Yii2 you can get the "name" of a controller inside the controller   by the `id`  this wary:

```
      $this->id;
```

This value return the lowercase name of the controller and if this is related to your model you can properly convert in the notation you need.